# Scale ItemsControl items (lines) using Slider value

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, scale, itemscontrol

In my WPF application (created using C# and Visual Studio), I have an ItemsControl; the items are instances of a custom class, Line. The Line class contains the x and y coordinates of the line:

```
public class Line{
    private double _x1, _y1, _x2, _y2;
    public double X1{
        get{ return _x1; }
        set{ _x1 = value; }
    }
    public double Y1{
        get{ return _y1; }
        set{ _y1 = value; }
    }
    public double X2{
        get{ return _x2; }
        set{ _x2 = value; }
    }
    public double Y2{
        get{ return _y2; }
        set{ _y2 = value; }
    }
}
```

The line representing a Line instance is bound (using Data Binding) to these start and end points.
In another part of the window there is a Slider which should represent the scale value of the application. Now I want the behaviour so that when I drag the scale Slider, the lines should scale according to the Slider's value. How can I achieve this?

I tried to change the getter methods like this one:

```
public double X1{
    get{ return _x1*scale; }
    set{ _x1 = value; }
}
```

But then I have 2 problems:
1) Where do I get the "scale" value from? The Line class does not know about the MainWindow or the Slider.
2) I managed to get the "scale" value from the Slider using a bad programming style (using a static public "currentSlider" property) like here:

```
public class MainWindow{
    public static Slider currentSlider;
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponents();
        currentSlider = slider1;
    }
}
```

Then the Line class can access the scale value and new lines are created using the right scale factor. But when I move the Slider, the lines do not get updated and scaled.

So how can I make the lines scale according to the value of the Slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question suggests that you want to scale the start and end points of the Line, but not the rendered stroke thickness. Hence you can't simply apply a transform to the `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` property of the Line in the DataTemplate.

An alternative would be to use a Path with a LineGeometry. As the LineGeometry has a `StartPoint` and an `EndPoint` property instead of the `X1`, `Y1`, `X2` and `Y2` of the Line class, you would however either use a binding converter, or change your item class into something like this:

```
public class Line
{
    public Point P1 { get; set; }
    public Point P2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your ItemsControl you would now bind the LineGeometry's `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` properties, and put a ScaleTransform into the LineGeometry's `Transform`. The ScaleTransform has the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties, which would be bound to the Slider's `Value`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Path.Data>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding P1}" EndPoint="{Binding P2}">
                        <LineGeometry.Transform>
                            <ScaleTransform
                                ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
                        </LineGeometry.Transform>                                
                    </LineGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
...
<Slider x:Name="slider" Width="200" Minimum="1" Maximum="10"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  
Using two points instead of direct coordinates in the Line class is no problem, it is even cleaner code.  
The the stroke thickness should not be scaled, that is a good point. I will try your code tomorrow and will see if it produces the expected results.  
I suppose there is a TranslateTransform as well? Can I create my own Transform class as well?

Comment: You can easily combine Transforms like ScaleTransform, TranslateTransform and RotateTransforms in a TransformGroup. There is also a MatrixTransform that can do all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ScaleTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) page on MSDN. Using the `ScaleTransform` object, you have a choice on how the lines would be scaled, eg. from their centre, or from the left or right, etc.

Comment: This could be a possible solution, but then I have to translate the lines as well, and the translation coordinates have no direct dependency to the slider value, so a changed slider value would not update the line positions. (sorry that I may not upvote your answer yet, too few reputation.)